# RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (2, 20, 256), got (2, 50, 256)

Tags: lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I get this error while trying to build a multiclass text classification network using LSTM (RNN). The code seems to run fine for the training part of the code whereas it throws the error for the validation part. Below is the network architecture and training code. Appreciate any help here.

I tried taking an existing code that predicts sentiment using RNN and replaced sigmoid with softmax function in the end and loss function from BCE Loss to NLLLoss()

---

```
  def forward(self, x, hidden):
    """
    Perform a forward pass of our model on some input and hidden state.
    """
    batch_size = x.size(0)
    embeds = self.embedding(x)
    lstm_out,hidden= self.lstm(embeds,hidden)

     # stack up lstm outputs
    lstm_out = lstm_out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_dim)

    # dropout and fully-connected layer
    out = self.dropout(lstm_out)
    out = self.fc(out)

    # softmax function
    soft_out = self.sof(out)

    # reshape to be batch_size first
    soft_out = soft_out.view(batch_size, -1)
#         soft_out = soft_out[:, -1] # get last batch of labels

    # return last sigmoid output and hidden state
    return soft_out, hidden


def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
    ''' Initializes hidden state '''
    # Create two new tensors with sizes n_layers x batch_size x hidden_dim,
    # initialized to zero, for hidden state and cell state of LSTM
    weight = next(self.parameters()).data

    if (train_on_gpu):
        hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda(),
              weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda())
    else:
        hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_(),
                  weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_())

    return hidden
```

---

```
# Instantiate the model w/ hyperparams
vocab_size = len(vocab_to_int)+1
output_size = 44
embedding_dim = 100
hidden_dim = 256
n_layers = 2

net = ClassificationRNN(vocab_size, output_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers)

print(net)
```

---

```
# loss and optimization functions
lr=0.001

criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)

# training params

epochs = 4 # 3-4 is approx where I noticed the validation loss stop decreasing

counter = 0
print_every = 100
clip=5 # gradient clipping

# move model to GPU, if available
if(train_on_gpu):
    net.cuda()

net.train()
# train for some number of epochs
for e in range(epochs):
    # initialize hidden state
    h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)

    # batch loop
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        counter += 1

        if(train_on_gpu):
            inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()

        # Creating new variables for the hidden state, otherwise
        # we'd backprop through the entire training history
        h = tuple([each.data for each in h])

        # zero accumulated gradients
        net.zero_grad()

        # get the output from the model
        output, h = net(inputs, h)

#         print('output:',output.squeeze())
#         print('labels:',labels.float())

        # calculate the loss and perform backprop
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss.backward()
        # `clip_grad_norm` helps prevent the exploding gradient problem in RNNs / LSTMs.
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), clip)
        optimizer.step()

        # loss stats
        if counter % print_every == 0:
            # Get validation loss
            val_h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)
            val_losses = []
            net.eval()
            for inputs, labels in valid_loader:

                # Creating new variables for the hidden state, otherwise
                # we'd backprop through the entire training history
                val_h = tuple([each.data for each in val_h])

                if(train_on_gpu):
                    inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()

                output, val_h = net(inputs, val_h)

                val_loss = criterion(output, labels)

                val_losses.append(val_loss.item())

            net.train()
            print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(e+1, epochs),
                  "Step: {}...".format(counter),
                  "Loss: {:.6f}...".format(loss.item()),
                  "Val Loss: {:.6f}".format(np.mean(val_losses)))
```

---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-805ed880b453> in <module>()
     58                     inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()
     59 
---> 60                 output, val_h = net(inputs, val_h)
     61 
     62                 val_loss = criterion(output, labels)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    488         else:
--> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

<ipython-input-38-dbfb8d384231> in forward(self, x, hidden)
     34         batch_size = x.size(0)
     35         embeds = self.embedding(x)
---> 36         lstm_out,hidden= self.lstm(embeds,hidden)
     37 
     38          # stack up lstm outputs
```

Answer (score 16):

Try adding `drop_last=True` in your line of codes that loads data using DataLoader,
for example for loading training data from data set `train_data`:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size, drop_last=True)
```

**Explanation**:

The error may caused by your training data not being divisible by batch size. Suppose your training data has 130 items and batch size is 8, the last batch will have only 2 (remainder of 130/8) items. Therefore by setting `drop_last` to `True`, the 2 items will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the size of `hidden` doesn't match your model. The second dim of a 3D tensor is typically the sequence length. I would suggest you to print the sizes of `embeds` and `hidden` in the evaluation phase.